# Issue with multiple crawlers on Solr custom search index

Tags: solr, indexing

I have custom search Index(SOLR) which has two root locations defined, one points to /home node and another points to repository(videos), we also have indexing strategy(onPublishEndAsync) in place.

```
<locations hint="list:AddCrawler">
 <crawler type="Sitecore.ContentSearch.SitecoreItemCrawler, Sitecore.ContentSearch">
    <Database>web</Database>
    <Root>path to home node</Root>
 </crawler>
 <crawler type="Sitecore.ContentSearch.SitecoreItemCrawler, Sitecore.ContentSearch">
    <Database>web</Database>
    <Root>path to repository items</Root>
 </crawler>
</locations>
```

Problem which i am observing is- item from the second root location is not getting indexed(in this case repository items), if i move this to first, it index the repository items and not items under home node.

However, if i rebuild the index manually from indexing manager, everything works as expected.

Anyone have thoughts here? what is missing here to make sure indexing strategy works with multiple roots as well.

I am using **Sitecore 8.1 (rev. 160302)**

Comment: Try renaming second `crawler` tag to `crawler2` like that: `<crawler ...<Root>Home</Root></crawler><crawler2>...<Root>Repository</root><crawler2>`

Comment: Hi @MarekMusielak, 
thank you for the suggestion, but i have already tried this option, but it is not working. https://community.sitecore.net/developers/f/5/t/2112

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We had the exact same issue as well with Lucene indexes.  Sitecore was able to provide a patch for the SitecoreItemCrawler class.  It doesn't appear to be on their Github so I can't link it but ask for support DLL 108165.

The issue is fixed in Sitecore 8.2 Update 1

Comment: To add some more clarity to this, the issue was that `SitecoreItemCrawler` was adding the item to the "list of already indexed items" before checking whether the item was relevant to the current crawler. When the second crawler got the item, it was already in the processed list so it was skipped. We worked around it by creating our own patch, but it did the same as the official patch do it's not worth posting.

Answer (score 2):

I've encountered the same problem a few weeks ago for **Sitecore 8.1** ([public repo link](https://github.com/WeTeam/WeBlog/pull/216)) and Lucene configuration.

Starting from the update **160302** different behaviour for multiple index crawlers can be observed.

For **Sitecore 8.1 rev. 151207** everything worked fine, right now, if you have multiple crawlers defined, only first is fired.

I've decompiled sources and observed that there are some changes that can cause such a behaviour.

### Workaround

We've solved the issue by creating separate indexes for each database (one for **master** and one for **web**).

If this is something you can do I highly recommend that (none of default Sitecore configs has multiple crawlers defined so it is probably safer to go this way)

Comment: Hi @AlanPłócieniak, Thanks for the information, i have two crawlers on the same database, pointing to different items. Rather than creating two indexes, i can directly use the default web index, but i am not wishing to use web index, as it contains everything. So this will be the last option.

Comment: I would recommend you to create a Sitecore support ticket for that if you can. You will probably get an answer faster there as this is a platform issue.

Comment: Thank you, i will raise a support ticket. Already @LyleJordan, answered saying they got patch for it. So this would be the ideal option.